# Making a customized range slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a customized range slider for temperature variation as seen in the image(the curved slider with a red handle):
[image: Temperature Monitor]

I tried using the jQuery Range Slider and a fiddle I found, `LINK :`http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/3/

But I'm unable to divide the slider into parts(as seen in the image), with each part representing a temperature value.

Could someone please help me accomplishing this?
Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add following to css to your code. You can change the value of border as per your requirement of no of parts:

```
#arc-slider .rs-border.rs-outer {
 border: 3px dotted #51c5cf;
}

#arc-slider .rs-border.rs-inner {
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please try to run your code before submitting an answer.
The solution you've provided is nowhere near to what is expected.
If it worked for you, please post your entire css from the fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this css in your fiddle only. Just pasted it below your css. Paste this css at the end in the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/3/

Comment: I think you didn't understand the query.
Your solution does not break the slider path into parts, with each part representing a temperature value as shown in the image. It just gives a dotted path to the slider.
Thanks anyways.